# Reversed Bubble High chart

Tags: json, highcharts

I have tried to implemented reversed bubble chart with high chart for cost relative value.
Where i have plotted "cost" as reversed value.

It is working correctly when i have taken 'cost' as reversed value only at x-axis. data has automatically reverse.

Getting issue when take 'cost' as reversed value both end at x-axis, y-axis. data is not reverse, and display wrong plotting.

I have created this jsfiddle example bind with my data. please refer this:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/muz0tave/4/][1]
```

Please help out of plotting/displaying data with high chart.

Comment: Could you please place your code in the jsfiddle? The one I opened is about daily fat intake and sugar.

Comment: @AnnaJeanine sure, please refer this : http://jsfiddle.net/muz0tave/4/

Comment: Can you replicate the issue with this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ncLe95ff/? I cannot see that reversed axes cause that the plotting is wrong.